# EF best way to load hierarchy(need all items)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

So I have a hierarchy, and I have a recursive function to build the children. At each level, would it be better to do `Parent.Children` (lazy loaded) or `Context.Whatever.Where(x => x.ParentId == currentItemId)`

I'm looking for other suggestions also if there's a better way to load the hierarchy. Would it be better to get all items in one query, then build the hierarchy in memory?

Some more detail that might help: 
This is just used to build a tree. So each "level" just needs an id and title really. I just have one simple tree(each item has a ParentId)

Comment: Do all rows in your table form a single tree, or do you store multiple smaller sub-trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple considerations on reading hierarchies from RDBMS:

- **If you need all children from every parent, load them "eagerly"** - Minimizing the number of round-trips to the database server is the most common trick to get your DB-accessing application run faster.
- **If you access a small percentage of children, and you want all parents, lazy loading may be better** - When you need to see the parent before deciding on whether to check the children or not, and most of your decisions turn out that you do not check the children, go for the lazy loading: a round-trip or two wouldn't hurt as much as bringing ten or twenty times more data than you need.
- **There are situations when you cannot read the whole hierarcy** - For example, because only the immediate parent `ID` is available. A common trick in this case is to make a "hierarchy ID" from the `ID` of the root parent, and add it as a field to all descendents. This field lets you retrieve the whole hierarchy in one go, and then fix up the references in memory.

To make a decision you should build a small prototype, populate its data table with enough rows for profiling to make sense, and profile the query both ways. Note that it is useless to profile the query on a nearly empty database, because the timing would be dominated by round-trips.

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on the children data, then eager-load it. If the child data is only used if certain conditions are met, then I would let it lazy-load the children.